# Can you apply a retention policy to users within a group on O365?

Tags: backup, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I am attempting to apply a retention policy to users added to a specific group in Office 365, yet I cannot seem to find a way to accomplish this.

The closest I have come is the ability to apply the policy to a group `as is` but it does not apply the policy to new users you add to said group.

Is this possible?  If so, what would be the best approach to this in an environment that needs to do this often?

Any feedback or direction is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. However, you can apply the retention policy to all users in a specific group via the following command as a workaround:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember DGName |foreach{Set-Mailbox $_.name -RetentionPolicy "Policy Name"}
```